# Finding the two planes which contains a given line and forms an angle of $60^\circ$ with a given plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am given the following question:

> Find the equations of the two planes that contain the line $r \{ x=z+1=y+2$ and form a $60^\circ$ angle with the plane $ \pi \{ x+2y-3z+2=0$

My solution:

Lets call the normal vector of the planes wanted $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$

The vector of the line is $\vec{v} =(1,1,1)$ and since it is perpendicular to the planes we want,

$$
(1,1,1) \cdot (a,b,c) = 0 \therefore a+b+c = 0
$$

Also, since the angles between the plane $\pi$ and our new planes is $60^\circ$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\vert (a,b,c) \cdot (1,2,-3) \vert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \sqrt{14}}
$$

I need another equation to finish the exercise, but **I'm not sure what is that third equation**.

**Textbook's answer**

$$
\pi_1 \{ 2x-3y+z-5=0\\
\pi_2 \{ 3x -y-2z-4=0
$$

Thank you.

Comment: The reason you are missing an equation is because there are many normal vectors to a plane, all proportional to each other. So you need to fix one paramater, for instance, look for the normalized vector, where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since as has been oft remarked the lenght of $(a,b,c)$ is variable let us chose the length to be $\sqrt{14}$ in order to cancel with the other $\sqrt{14}$
So we have the equations:

$$a+b+c=0$$
$$a+2b-3c=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{14}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\frac{1}{2}14=7$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=14$$

If we take the first two 
$$a+b+c=0$$
$$a+2b-3c=7$$
and solve them we get

$$a=-5c-7$$

$$b=4c+7$$

If we now substitute into the third equation and simplify we get 
$$c^2+3c+2=0$$ so $c=-1,-2$.

This gives us the two vectors
$$(-2,3,-1) \text{and} (3,-1,-2).$$

And the two equations
$$2x-3y+z=d$$
$$3x-y-2z=d$$

The value of $d$ can then be calculated in each case since the plane passes through $(0,-2,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you Rene, I appreciate that. Best Regards, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that there is no "one" normal vector to a plane. There are infinitely many, but all have the same direction.
A third equation may come from choosing the norm of your vector (example, by setting it to $1/\sqrt{14}$ : $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} = 1/\sqrt{14}$

Now you have 2 equations, easily solvable given that this third equation simplifies your second one :)

But, I believe the question should state that the 60° angle can be either positive or negative (otherwise, there would be only one plane).